# Does a transaction affect all queries?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions

I started a transaction using `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in Management Studio but I forgot to ROLLBACK or COMMIT it for about 10 minutes. I freaked out and went back to ROLLBACK my changes. Did this rollback all queries that went through the server during that time or just through my user/connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just your connection :-)

(Edit: rather your transaction, since the BEGIN TRANSACTION. If you did updates before the BEGIN TRANSACTION in the same session, they will of course not be rolled back)

BUT: It could have given SELECTs of other sessions the wrong answer depending on what lock types and query hints that were being used...

An example:

In one SQL Studio session, do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE a(a INT)

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE  a 
SET a = 2

SELECT *, @@TRANCOUNT
FROM a
```

-> You will see '2, 1' as result

Open a new session (tab in Sql studio)

Do:

```
SELECT *, @@TRANCOUNT
FROM a (NOLOCK)
```

You will see '2, 0'

Now, in first session, do

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

SELECT *, @@TRANCOUNT
FROM a
```

-> transaction rolled back, and you see '1, 0'

-> a select in second session will also show '1, 0'

so: If you use (NOLOCK) hint, you can get uncommitted data as result -> which might lead to very unexpected effects :-)

Dont forget:

```
DROP TABLE a
```

when you're done ;)

Answer (score 3):

It should only affect your transaction, so only things that were done in your session during that time.

Comment: You also might have locked the table from other users you made a change on too.

Comment: I think I did lock out everyone from the table.

Answer (score 1):

You're fine.  All the other queries will go through just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It should roll back all queries made in the transaction, so it is more specific than your user\connection and definitely not all queries on the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_transactions) properties of transactions. You see that there is nothing to worry about if a transaction is rolled back or committed it has no effect on the outcome of other transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Your rollback affects only your transaction. The I in ACID.

However, the rows, pages or whole table you locked will affect other users if they want to use them. It depends on:

- what they want to do
- lock timeout
- client command timeout